# Mediator Pattern with Non colleague classes

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-analysis, mediator

I have read the mediator pattern and the idea is clear to me. However, one thing that struck my mind is the code for the mediator pattern becomes much easier is we use the colleague classes in the mediator. That is, the objects that want to communicate derive from the same base class. However, in a lot of scenarios we need similar kind of communication where several objects are involved, however they are not necessarily colleagues. Is mediator still the way to go, or is there a better approach ?
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the colleagues to inherit from the mediator? What's the problem with "several objects are involved?". A better approach for what? Please rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

The mediator pattern defines an object that encapsulates how a set of objects interact. Here colleagues are those how wants to communicate together to accomplish a task. The colleagues need not be having similar responsibilities. Therefore it is absolutely fine if you go with mediator pattern.

But remember that the colleague class should only have the responsibility to pass the message for the sake of communication and nothing else.